# How can I have different UIUserNotificationSettings when there are many kinds of Notification

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

In my project I have a problem: there are two different notifications.

One of them need two `UIMutableUserNotificationActions` (OK and Cancel) and the other needs only one (Remind me later).

Here is the code:

```
let completeAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
completeAction.identifier = "OK" // the unique identifier for this action
completeAction.title = "OK" // title for the action button
completeAction.activationMode = .Background // UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background - don't bring app to foreground
completeAction.authenticationRequired = false // don't require unlocking before performing action
completeAction.destructive = true // display action in red

let cancelAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
cancelAction.identifier = "Cancel"
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    cancelAction.parameters = [UIUserNotificationTextInputActionButtonTitleKey : "Send"]
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
cancelAction.title = "Cancel"
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    cancelAction.behavior = UIUserNotificationActionBehavior.TextInput
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
cancelAction.activationMode = .Background
cancelAction.destructive = false
cancelAction.authenticationRequired = false

let todoCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory() // notification categories allow us to create groups of actions that we can associate with a notification
todoCategory.identifier = "TODO_CATEGORY"
todoCategory.setActions([cancelAction, completeAction], forContext: .Minimal) // UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default (4 actions max)

application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge , .Sound], categories: NSSet(array: [todoCategory]) as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>))
```

But there's only one condition of `UIUserNotificationSettings`.

Comment: Do not post your code as an image. Update your question with the actual code copy and pasted into the question (and properly formatted).

Comment: @rmaddy i have fixed. Thx. it's my first time ask question. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally , i found an answer and solve my problem perfectly. I copy the code here in case someone find the same problem that i did.

there's a way that IOS allow you have different notification actions, UIMutableUserNotificationCategory

```
 let cancelCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory() // notification categories allow us to create groups of actions that we can associate with a notification
    cancelCategory.identifier = "Notification_Category"
    cancelCategory.setActions([cancelAction], forContext: .Default) //
```

And

```
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge , .Sound], categories: NSSet(array: [todoCategory,cancelCategory]) as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>)
```

method allow you have several notification categories.

Last step. when you backend wanna push a notification. you just should build a part of key value ("category"=>"your category identifier"), and every thing has done.

```
 (body['aps'] = array('alert' => '','sound' => 'default','link_url' => '','category' => 'Notification_Category',);)
```